# Solving a dependency issue

Tags: dependencies, structure

Have a look at the following diagram...

[image: Assembly Dependency Diagram]

The arrows show the dependencies each of the assemblies has.

I'm trying, where possible, to keep the 'contamination' from one layer to another to a minimum and thought I was doing OK.

My Service layer knows about the Business Entities and the DAL later knows about the Data Transfer Objects and I use the translators to convert the types where necessary.

As you might expect, the Service implementation needs to make calls on the DAL via the interface and this is where I've come unstuck. Even though I'm using the translators the Service Implementation still needs to know about the types defined in the DTOs (or, alternatively) the DAL needs to know about the BEs.

Is there a way around this?

If not, am I right in thinking that the minimum level of 'contamination' is achieved by allowing the Service *Implementation* to have a dependency on the DTOs?

If anyone has any thoughts on this subject, I'd be delighted to hear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that some 'contamination' is inevitable and that doing it this way at least reduced that to a minimum.